# Mysql query - amount spent by customer

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

I am trying to write a query to pull amount of money spent by each customer.  I have not been able to find anything searching the site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try a plugin for this, https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-customer-relationship-manager/5712695

Comment: Thank you Akshat, however I would really like to know the query so that I can customize the output for my needs.

Comment: if you are building a new site then you can add amount to user's meta on every order complete, and if you want to implement on older site then I think it's be better to query to the db directly.

Comment: That's my question.  What is the query for the DB to pull this information?

Comment: you can loop through all orders and collect user id from orders along with the amount, and it'd be better to store them separately and for new orders you can store directly after the order is completed using woocommerce_order_status_completed hook.